# Passing a hex number that includes letters from an array of hex numbers to .setTint() not working properly

Tags: javascript, arrays, hex, phaser-framework

I have a following array of hex numbers, that are different characters in the game.

```
gameState.charactersArray = [0xff5c33, 0x324563, 0x000000, 0xffffff, 0x003300];
```

And if I try to access a number that includes letters, so indeces 0 and 3, then the character simply isn't displayed (btw, I'm not getting any errors logged to the console).
The hex numbers from that array composed only by numbers, so indeces 1, 2 and 4 work fine.

Also, if in the line:

```
gameState.character.setTint(gameState.charactersArray[gameState.characterIndex]);
```

I put any of the hex numbers with letters, for example `0xff5c33` instead of `gameState.charactersArray[gameState.characterIndex]` then it works fine too.

I just want to be able to set the character's color based on user's choice. Also `gameState.characterIndex` works fine, no issues there.

Answer (score 1):

Since *hex numbers* are `numbers` and both are treated the same *(in javascript)*, it should not matter, if you use the hex literal or the decimal form. So the problem is probably somewhere else, maybe the `gameState.characterIndex` is not correct, or the `tint` is added serveral times?

> **But** if you want to be on the save side, you could use the phaser [Color object](https://photonstorm.github.io/phaser3-docs/Phaser.Display.Color.html#toc0__anchor), with this you can convert into string, numbers, or access the single components.

**Here a demo, illustrating the previous mentioned points:**
*(if you use the color object, I would use it at the initialisation of the array, like `let colors = [Phaser.Display.Color.ValueToColor(0xff5c33),..]` or so.*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    backgroundColor: 0xcdcdcd,
    scene: {
        preload,
        create
    },
    banner: false
}; 

function preload(){
    this.load.image('img', 'http://labs.phaser.io/assets/sprites/copy-that-floppy.png');
}

function create () {
   
   let colors = [0xff5c33, 0x324563, 0x000000, 0xffffff, 0x003300];
   
   for(let idx = 0; idx < colors.length; idx++){
       let currentColor = colors[idx];
       let colorObj = Phaser.Display.Color.ValueToColor(currentColor); 
       let colorString = Phaser.Display.Color.RGBToString(colorObj.r, colorObj.g, colorObj.b);
       
       let img = this.add.image(10 + (idx * 90), 10 , 'img').setScale(.5).setOrigin(0);
       let text = this.add.text(10 + (idx * 90), 90, `${currentColor}\n${colorString}`, {color: colorString});
       img.setTint(currentColor);
   }
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser@3.55.2/dist/phaser.js"></script>
```

**Update *(from the comments)*:**
the array values for index 0 and 3 must have been overwriten somewhere.

Comment: I can see it work on your example, but I can't see how, nor i can apply it to my code. You said that you're using color object, but all I see in the code is that you're passing the `currentColor` directly into `img.setTint()`, which is what i did, and whatever is happening with `colorObj` doesn't seem to have any relevance to `img`. Like you said, problem might be somewhere else, but it's not `characterIndex`, i made an `alert` to pop every time user changes it, but the character will just disapear (if it's a hex number with letters). I may settle have to for finding colors just with numbers.

Comment: @chylinski I'm using the color object, in this example only to convert the value into a color string('#000000') just for the _text_ and the _text color_. So just to show the colors, and that the hex values still match. May there is no problem, and on your images the tinting doesn't have a visible effect, like the white tint. But without seeing more code it is, hard to tell, what causes the problem.. Sorry that I could be of much more help.

Comment: @chylinski you could output `gameState.charactersArray[gameState.characterIndex]` on change, into the browser console, and use the `Phaser.Display.Color.ValueToColor(...)` to verify, that the color values match.

Comment: the colors that it doesn't want to use, also won't be output to the console. The function that is responsible for choosing color is too long to put here and it seems fine. It's ok, thanks for trying anyway, gonna have to opt for alternative solution :)

Comment: @chylinski is nothing it "outputed" the those value must me overwriten somewhere, since as mentioned in the anwser a hex-number is just a number , the hex array is the same as `[16735283, 3294563, 0, 16777215, 13056]`. If you want to check it, just replace the hex array with the number array, if the values are still empty and the tint is not set, it is because, those values where overwriten.

Comment: yeah, i tried that, same.

Comment: @chylinski well then it is clear, the index 0 and 3, are overwriten somewhere in the code, hope it helps you fine the error in the code.

Comment: i won't find out what exactly anymore, got rid of the color choice in the end. Thanks again!